# Java: Starting a process in a thread and getting a reference to the created process

Tags: java, process

I have the following integration test code where I start various services before the test can run:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setup() throws Exception {

  // Set some vars like javaBin location

  ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(javaBin, "-jar", "app.jar");
  Process process = launchProcess(builder);

}

private static Process launchProcess(ProcessBuilder builder) throws IOException {

  AtomicReference<Process> process = new AtomicReference<>();
  new Thread(() -> {
    try {
      process.set(builder.start());

      BufferedReader processStd =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.get().getInputStream());     
      BufferedReader processErr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.get().getErrorStream()));

      // To prevent deadlocks due to limited buffer size
      String s = "";
      while(processStd .readLine() != null) {}
      while((s = processErr .readLine()) != null) {
          System.err.println(s);
      }
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }).start();

  return process.get();
}
```

The process starts OK, but I `process.get()` always returns `null`. What am I doing wrong? How can I get a reference to the started process using the above approach? If I set the process in the `setup()` function itself, i.e. `process = builder.start()`, then it works correctly. However, it also leads to a lot of repetition as I need to start numerous separate services in separate JVMs.

Comment: move `process.set(builder.start());` before the thread implementation and after `AtomicReference<Process> process = new AtomicReference<>();`

Comment: If your only reason for using a separate thread is to consume the process’s output, you can replace your entire launchProcess method with `builder.inheritIO().start();`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is most likely that the thread hasn't actually started by the time you return with `process.get()` at the end of `launchProcess`.

You will need to wait for the thread to actually start and execute the call to `process.set(builder.start())` before returning from your method.

This could be done with something as simple as a `CountDownLatch`.

```
private static Process launchProcess(ProcessBuilder builder) throws IOException {
  final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
  // ...
  new Thread(() -> {
    try {
      process.set(builder.start());
      latch.countDown();
      //...
    } catch (IOException e) {
      //...
    }
  }).start();

  latch.await();
  return process.get();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have given both this and a `Future` implementation a try. Although both successfully wait until the process is started, the processes all have `hasExited = true` by the time I am done starting them. How would I prevent the thread from exiting in this case? I merely need a reference to the process that is started.

Comment: Is there any reason you need to start this in a separate thread? If you need the thread, then you will need to have the thread wait until the process is complete by calling `waitFor` on the process object

Comment: The main reason for starting them in separate threads is to be able to get the services up and running in parallel, i.e. not have to wait for each of them to start up separately.  I'll give the `waitFor` approach a try.

Comment: We ended up simply writing a shell script that executes the `jar` files from the respective projects. It was much simpler than the use case presented, but sufficed for our needs. I'll still mark this as an answer as it did indeed answer the question.